# I want to add Soundwave while recording Audio in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i'm try to add sound-wave effect while recording audio but i don't find any way to add it, currently i am using react-native-audio library, if you have any solution then please help me.

i try to add custome soundwave by using react-native-wave-view

```
<WaveView
     height={50}
     width={wp('80%')}
     waveColor={'#0ff'}
     waveSpeed={'slow'}
     waveAmplitude={20}
     noOfWaves={70}
     wavePosition={'both'}
     style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center' }}
    />
```

but it dosn't show the effect as per record audio currentMetering, so if you have any solution please help me, thank you.